# How to prove that the minimum eigenvalue of the difference of two specific matrices is negative

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let us define two matrices:

1. Matrix $D$: diagonal matrix with positive entries
2. Matrix $A=s\cdot s^{T}$, where $s$ is a vector with norm one and non-zero entries.  Therefore, $A$ is symmetric with $\operatorname{rank}=1$ and single eigenvalue $\lambda= 1$

It is clear that if $D=k\cdot I$, for any constant $k$, the minimum eigenvalue of $M=D-A\cdot D\cdot A$ is zero. However, how can I prove that, for any other $D$,  the minimum eigenvalue of $M$ is negative??

Thanks!!!!

Comment: $D=I,\ A={\rm diag}\ (1,0,\cdots ,0)$ nonnegative.

Comment: The minimum eigenvalue of M is zero only if D=k*I, for any constant k. For any other diagonal matrix D, the minimum eigenvalue is negative. This is what I want to prove.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
M &= D-ADA \\
&= D^{1/2}(I-D^{-1/2}ADAD^{-1/2})D^{1/2}
\end{align}
$M$ is positive definite only when eigenvalues of $D^{-1/2}ADAD^{-1/2}$ are less than one.

Let $x$ be the non-zero eigenvector of $A$, so that $A=xx^\top$.
Because the non-zero eigenvalue of $D^{-1/2}ADAD^{-1/2} = x^\top D^{-1}xx^\top Dx$, you want to prove that
$$
x^\top D^{-1}xx^\top Dx>1
$$
for all vector $x:\|x\|=1$ and for all positive diagonal matrix $D$.

Maybe that can help.

Answer (score 0):

We know that min. eigen value is :  min ${x^T Mx}$; x is of unit norm.

Now $x^TMx = x^TDx-x^TA^TDAx= x^TDx-(Ax)^TD(Ax)$

Take x to be unit eigen vector of A corresponding to e.v. $1$ we have $Ax=x$, So

$x^TMx=0 $ implies min. eigen value is non positive.

NOTE: It might be zero even when $D$ is not equal to $kI$

HINT: Take $A=Diag(1,0,0)$ and $D= diag(1,2,3)$

Comment: Thanks, you are totally right. I did not contemplate this possibility, because for my specific problem matrix $A=uu^{T}$, where vector $u$ has no entry equal to zero. So I should have specified that I would like to proof that for theis kind of matrices $A$ the minimum eigenvalue is negative